# combining jquery click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am quite new to jquery and was wondering if someone could recommend some ways I could combine these functions together so that the code would be more efficient and slimmed down. I basically have two click functions that do the exact same thing but are targeting two different buttons. Thank you.

```
        $( ".step1 button" ).click(function() {     
            if ($(".step1 input").is(":checked")) { 
                $( ".step1").slideUp("slow",function(){
                    $(".step2").slideDown("slow");
                });
            } // end if
            else{
                $("div.error").remove();
                $(".step1.step-heading").append("<div class='error'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Please make a selection before continuing</div>");
            } // end else         
        })// end click function

        $( ".step2 button" ).click(function() {     
            if ($(".step2 input").is(":checked")) { 
                $( ".step2").slideUp("slow",function(){
                    $(".step3").slideDown("slow");
                });
            } // end if
            else{
                $("div.error").remove();
                $(".step2.step-heading").append("<div class='error'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Please make a selection before continuing</div>");
            } // end else         
        })// end click function
```

Comment: Did you check jQuery multiple selectors - [jQuery.com - Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the DOM element tha trigger the event by using `$(this)` inside the vent handler.

So, you simply have to attach the same handler to several elements, and use `$(this)` inside the implementation of the handler.

```
$(".step1 button").add(".step2 button").click(function() {
    // $(this) refered to the button tha triggered the event
}
```

To make easier to find the step number you can use a custom "data-" attribute, for example like this:

```
<button data-step-no="1">
```

You can get that attribute by using `$(this).attr('data-step-no')`, In fact, to add or substract, you need to parse it like this: `var stepno = parseInt($(this).attr('data-step-no')`.

To select all the buttons wit a single selector you can use buttons like this:

```
<button data-step-no="1" class="step">
<button data-step-no="2" class="step">
```

Ans select them all in a single step:

```
$('button .step').click(...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple refactor that will not require changes to HTML:

```
$('[class^="step"]').each(function(k, v) {
    var $btn       = $(v).find('button'),
        $input     = $(v).find('input'),
        $next      = $(v).next(),
        $heading   = $(v).find('.step-heading'),
        error_html = "<div class='error'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Please make a selection before continuing</div>";

    $btn.click(function(e) {
        if ($input.is(':checked')) {
            $(v).slideUp('slow', function() {
                $next.slideDown('slow');
            });
        } else {
            $('div.error').remove();
            $heading.append(error_html);
        }
    });
});
```